# Lie groups: Show $L_y \circ x_t = x_t \circ L_y$ where $x_t$ is the flow of a left invariant differentiable vector field

Tags: lie-groups

My definition of a left invariant vector field is one for which the equation $dL_xX = X$ is satisfied, where $X$ is the differentiable vector field and $x \in G$ where G is a Lie group.

Consider the two sides of the equation:

$L_y \circ x_t (p) = L_y(x_t(p)) = yx_t(p)$

$x_t \circ L_y (p) = x_t(L_y(p)) = x_t(yp))$

Why are these equal?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $\theta^{(p)}(t) = yx_t(p)$ and $\psi^{(p)}(t) = x_t(yp)$.  Compute both ${\theta^{(p)}}'(0)$ and ${\psi^{(p)}}'(0)$.  Then use uniqueness of integral curves.

Comment: In my calculation,  ${\theta^{(p)}}'(0) =\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} ~yx_t(p)=yX(p)$, but I don't know what is the $yX(p)$, since $y$ is a element of $G$, and $X(p)$ is a  tangent vector at $p$, I don't know what  $yX(p)$ is ? Namely, how do they multiply ?   Besides, ${\psi^{(p)}}'(0)=  \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} x_t(yp) = X(yp)$.   Seemly, I can't get $L_y \circ x_t = x_t \circ L_y$. Could you talk it detail ?  I meet this problem when I read the section 2 of chapter 1 of  do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry.  My knowledge background is very weak.  Could you talk it detail ? Thanks very much.